# How to exit Postgresql server?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

How do you exit from the PostgreSQL server one that started with sudo su - postgres?

Comment: no that question is for psql, mine is about the server

Comment: `sudo service postgresql stop`?

Comment: The server has nothing "to exit from"

Answer (score 4):

type `exit` and press enter. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Type `\q` and then press ENTER to quit psql.

Answer (score 0):

A simple exit command did the job.

Comment: That doesn't "exit the Postgres" server. That exits the shell you have opened.